# Convert RAW to JPEG (libjpeg.net)

Tags: .net, thumbnails, jpeg, libjpeg

Ok, here's the thing. 
In my app, I need to create a thumbnail in binary format (to save it into the database) for the user to see. The problem is that this is handled for the common image formats (.btm, .jpg, .png etc)

As requirements got updated, I need to implement further functionality for .raw images. Problems? Too many raw type formats (new format for a different camera manufacturer) and not specific code examples.

I found this library LibJpeg for the .Net framework (I am currently programming in C#), LibJpeg.Net that claims to handles these cases. However the specifications, or any tutorials, are absent.

Supposedly that the .Net version is identical to the C version (regarding the functions), which is the standard procedure for such undertaking?

Any other comments or suggestions are highly welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

If you download the LibJpeg.Net binaries from [here](http://bitmiracle.com/libjpeg.net_bin.zip), the downloaded archive contains a compiled HTML help file that contains both a getting started guide and full specification of both the classic and managed LibJpeg.Net API:s. As far as I know, the documentation is not available online.